# Cannot connect to AWS SES SMTP endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, ssl

I'm building an application that will use AWS SES to send email via SMTP.  I've properly configured a domain and confirmed I can send email from that domain using the AWS SDK.  I've created SMTP credentials and ensured the IAM user is properly configured with the right permissions.  I've written a test script that uses [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) to send the email.

The test script runs successfully using my personal development machine on my home network, but the script will NOT work when using the development laptop issued by my corporate client on my home network.  The corporate laptop runs many security tools, including ZScaler.  I also know that, due to the ZScaler service, NPM must be set to use a self-signed certificate (the command is `npm config set cafile {CA_FILEPATH}`).

I don't know why the script won't work on the corporate laptop, and I would appreciate some help in figuring what to try next.

Here's the script:

```
'use strict';

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const runtest = async function() {
    console.debug('Creating the SMTP transport');
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: 'myusername',
        pass: 'mypassword',
      },
    });

    console.debug('Building mail options');
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'me@example.com',
      to: 'you@example.com',
      subject: 'subject',
      text: 'body',
      html: '<h1>Hi</h1',
    };

    console.debug('Sending mail...');
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.debug(`Sent mail.  Info: ${JSON.stringify(info, null, 2)}`);
    console.info('Message sent!');
};
runtest().catch(console.error);
```

Here's the result when run from the corporate laptop:

```
Creating the SMTP transport
Building mail options
Sending mail...
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:200:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'read',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Playing with TLS settings such as `rejectUnauthorized: false` and specifying the TLS version
- Connecting to or disconnecting from the corporate VPN
- I found a reference on [this Github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19456) that suggested testing the connection with `openssl`.  I ran this command `openssl s_client -connect email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:465`, and this was the result (seems ok):

```
CONNECTED(0000021C)
write:errno=10054
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 336 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: whats your node version in your corporate laptop. try to use a node version above v12 and see if it hppens

Comment: Fair question.  my laptop is currently using v12.15.0.

Comment: Please try latest than that. 13 or 14

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the node version that caused this error. I have upgraded my node version to v12.x to fix the issue.

Comment: My laptop is currently using v12.15.0, and I used NVM for Windows to install 14.9.0, refresh the packages, and try again.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result.  Thank you for the suggestion, however.

Comment: sorry that it didnt help you. after you install did you make sure that the nodejs is 14 when you test it. you can do `node -v` to confirm it

Comment: Yes, I ran that command to confirm the version, deleted all local npm packages, and reinstalled them before running the tests.